# Full window shortcut with keyboard module

Tags: python, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to press the shortcut for full window on my mac (cmd+ctrl+f) with my python script using the keyboard module but I get the quick search shortcut (cmd+f).

I tried:

```
import keyboard

keyboard.send("cmd+ctrl+f")
```

```
keyboard.press_and_release("cmd+ctrl+f")
```

```
keyboard.press("cmd+ctrl+f")
```

```
keyboard.press("cmd")
keyboard.press("ctrl")
keyboard.press("f")

keyboard.release("f")
```

but nothing works. When running in terminal it goes to quick search so cmd+f but I never get full screen terminal.